# import numba on mac Sierra

Tags: python, macos, numba

I'm trying to install NUMBA on a mac machine (10.12.6). 
I've tried with CONDA:

```
conda install numba
```

I'm getting this:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/lefaa/miniconda2:
#numba                     0.35.0              np113py27_6
```

This seems good, however when I try (using python 2.7):

```
python -c "from numba import jit"
```

I'm getting that the numba module isn't installed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numba
```

Do I have to configure something else?

Comment: You should use a standard routine: `pip install numba`.

Comment: `conda` has been the standard way installing `numba` for quite some time. In fact that's the recommended method and pip support I believe is only fairly recent.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your path is not set up correctly and the python that conda installed numba into is not the one you are running. If you run `which python` you should get the one that's in your `miniconda2` if everything is working properly. If you get a different python executable then you probably need to set your `PATH` environment variable. See:

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html#installing-conda-on-a-system-that-has-other-python-installations-or-packages

Comment: I think the installation has been done correctly since my $PATH variable contains in the beginning '/Users/lefaa/miniconda2/bin' and when I type 'which python' I get '/Users/lefaa/miniconda2/bin/python' –

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Indeed, when installing with conda, conda installs the target package in python associated to conda (i.e, in this python '/Users/lefaa/miniconda2/bin/python'). So to import numba, it is necessary to lunch the python of miniconda. 
However, to install numba on the main python (python2.7), one solution will be to install like this '/usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install numba'.